# How to install Google Play on Kindle Fire 7" (2016)?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, amazon-kindle-fire

I'm trying to install Google Play (and rest of Google services) on my Kindle Fire 7" model 2016. I've done little bit of research and noticed that things change rapidly. I'm looking for verified and latest way of getting this installed without rooting my Kindle, is that possible? I'm trying to be able to install any Android app from  the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 2):

[This android police article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/07/25/install-play-store-amazon-fire-tablet/) describes how to do it without root. In short:

Enable install of "Apps from Unknown Sources" in Settings.

Install in order:

1. Google Account Manager APK
2. Google Services Framework APK
3. Google Play Services APK
4. Google Play Store APK

...profit!